# Pandas: Why does the length of an empty list equal 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In the example DataFrame, why is the length of an empty list 1? I'd expect an empty list to be of length 0; as `len([]) == 0`.

#### Use case:

I'm trying to count the number of values in each row, where the values are a string of comma separated integers, or alpha-numeric.

---

#### Example:

Create the sample dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['1,2,3,4', '1,2,3', '1,2', '1A, 363C', 
                   '1,1-33', '26a, Green House', '** All **', '', '']})

df['col1']

0             1,2,3,4
1               1,2,3
2                 1,2
3            1A, 363C
4              1,1-33
5    26a, Green House
6           ** All **
7                    
8                    
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Split the string on comma to create lists of values:

```
df['col1'].str.split(',')

0           [1, 2, 3, 4]
1              [1, 2, 3]
2                 [1, 2]
3            [1A,  363C]
4              [1, 1-33]
5    [26a,  Green House]
6            [** All **]
7                     []
8                     []
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

*Try* and determine the length of each list:

```
df['col1'].str.split(',').map(len)

0    4
1    3
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    1
7    1  <-- Expedted to be 0
8    1  <-- Expected to be 0
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

---

#### Questions:

- Why is the length of an empty list 1?

  - As pointed out by @Timus, using `.map(repr)` shows the list isn't empty: `['']`. Thank you.
- What would be a better approach for this use-case?

Comment: List isn't empty. Try `print(df['col1'].str.split(',').map(repr))`.

Comment: How should `a,b,,c` be counted? 3 or 4?

Comment: An example such as `a,b,,c` would not occur in this dataset. However, it should be counted as 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try [`str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html)

```
df['count'] = df['col1'].str.count(r'[^,]+')
```

---

```
      col1  count
0  1,2,3,4      4
1    1,2,3      3
2      1,2      2
3       1A      1
4               0
```

Comment: Interesting, concise approach. This performs well on the real dataset, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The last one has the empty string.

```py
>>> ''.split(',')
['']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the empty strings as 0 you can mask them:

```
df['col1'].str.split(',').str.len().mask(df['col1'].eq(''),0)
```

Note however that `split`+`len` is not the most straightforward approach. You can just count the separators (`,`). Then add 1 wherever the string is not empty:

```
df['col1'].str.count(',').add(df['col1'].ne(''))
```

Output:

```
0    4
1    3
2    2
3    1
4    0
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you,  I thought about counting commas as well. However, given the real dataset, it would lead to several inaccuracies.  I'll try the `mask` approach.

Comment: Which inaccuracies? Can you show a sample of the real data?

Comment: Apologies, I have updated the question to show a more representative dataset (was going for minimal before).  I might have mis-spoken and counting commas might be an option. However, I'm going to go with the concise regex approach. I appreciate your time, thank you - upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Timus for the insight to use `.map(repr)` to reveal the non-empty list as `['']`.

---

#### Solution:

Replace all empty string values with `NaN`:

```
df['col1'].replace('', float('nan'), inplace=True)
```

Apply a lambda statement to split and count, if the value is not a `float`:

```
df['count'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split(',')) if not isinstance(x, float) else 0)
```

Result:

```
    col1    count
0   1,2,3,4     4
1   1,2,3       3
2   1,2         2
3   1A          1
4   NaN         0
```